# Chart.js doesn't read input data coming from observable (Angular)

Tags: angular, chart.js, observable

I'm in the middle of creating a chart based on some data but I stuck. My problem is that the data which comes from a parent component doesn't get recognized by Chart.JS for some reason.

An example of how my **data** looks like:

```
[
{month: 'January', revenue: 100}, 
{month: 'February', revenue: 140}..
]
```

I get the data, send it into my parent container component, subscribe in the template using async pipe and use Input in the child component to access the data.

Child Component:

```
export class MonthlySalesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() soldUnitsPerMonth!: any;

  @ViewChild('chart')
  private chartRef!: ElementRef;
  private chart!: Chart;

  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Interesting Data',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5],
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }

  getAllMonths() {
    return this.soldUnitsPerMonth.map((item: any) => item.month);
  }
}
```

Instead of hard-coded values in the labels and data arrays I wanted to get access to every month (and every revenue) hence I created getAllMonths function.

The problem is, even if I write those functions, the new Chart constructor cannot access it because the Input data is still undefined. I don't understand why since if I access it using a ul/li - ngFor method I can easily render the data on the UI. But for some reason, new Chart cannot get access to this data.

I read a tip to use ngAfterViewInit hook but that didn't help either.

Child template:

```
<canvas #chart width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

The problem was that the data arrived in an async way and was not yet ready when the component was created. Hence, I had to wrap the new Chart logic into an observable and then used switchMap to take advantage of its higher-order ability.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setChart().subscribe();
  }

  setChart() {
    return this.soldUnitsPerMonth.pipe(
      switchMap((items) => {
        return this.defineChartDetails(items);
      })
    );
  }

  defineChartDetails(items: any) {
    return new Observable((obs) => {
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.destroy();
      }

      this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: items.map((item: any) => item.month + 1),
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Interesting Data',
              data: items.map((item: any) => item.totalSalesInMonth),
            },
          ],
        },
      });
    });
  }
```

If anyone runs into this problem, please note that you also have to unsubscribe from the setChart method using ngOnDestroy.